# How to add other fields than the name and email address in custom module?

Tags: magento2

How to add other fields than the name and email address, for example, the company field that I added, it is not sent.
What is not done?

And who can say , for what this const

> const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME='trans_email/ident_support/name';
>
> const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL='trans_email/ident_support/email';
>
> Controller/Index/Post.php

```
<?php
  namespace Quotemail\Customemail\Controller\Index;

  class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

    {

     const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME='trans_email/ident_support/name';

     const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL='trans_email/ident_support/email';

     protected $_inlineTranslation;

     protected $_transportBuilder;

     protected $_scopeConfig;

     protected $_logLoggerInterface;

     public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
    array $data = []

    )
{
    $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_logLoggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
    $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();


    parent::__construct($context);


    }

   public function execute()

   {

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    try
    {
        // Send Mail
        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $post['name'],
            'email' => $post['email'],
            'company' => $post['company']
        ];

        $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig - >getValue(

        'trans_email/ident_general/email',

         \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE

        );

        $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue(

        'trans_email/ident_general/name',

         \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars([
                'name'  => $post['name'],
                'email'  => $post['email'],
                'company' => $post['company']
            ])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName,$post['company'])
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Email sent successfully');

    } catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }

  }
}
```

> customemail_index_index.phtml

```
 <form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'customemail/index/post/';?>" name="customemaildata" method="post" id="contactForm-1" data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <div class="field email required">
        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Name') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo __('Name') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field email required">
        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field company required">
        <label class="label" for="company"><span><?php  echo __('Company') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="company" id="company" title="<?php echo __('Company') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-company':true}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
            <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: get company in your email template as similar to name in html file